# Errors in queue Buffer and file cause to terminate my app

Tags: android, emulation

When I run my app, it immediately terminates before running any activity and this errors appear in logcat:

> system_process E/Surface: queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to
>   SurfaceTexture, -19 system_process E/TaskPersister: File error
>   accessing recents directory (directory doesn't exist?).

It was running correctly and this problem occured after making changes in some xml files.

When I searched for a solution, all the answers say that the problem not from code, it is from hardware, but I can not specify the exact problem. I am using genymotion as an emulator.

Could please any one help me ?!

Answer (score 0):

I could know The error by using real device instead of genymotion. Null Pointer Exception appear in logcat. So, the problem from code not from hardware, but with genymotion, no clear exception error given.